# CLLocationManagerDelegate functions not called

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have a separate class named LocationService

```
class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var locationCallback: ((CLLocation?) -> Void)!
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    public func getCurrentLocation (_ completion: @escaping(CLLocation?) -> Void) {
        if PermissionManager.hasLocationPermission() && CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            self.locationCallback = completion
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("LOCATIONS: ", locations)
        locationCallback(locations.first)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("LOCATION ERROR: ", error)
        locationCallback(nil)
    }
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
        print("LOCATION: ", newLocation)
        locationCallback(newLocation)
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("DEINIT LOCATION SERVICE")
    }

}
```

If I trigger `getCurrentLocation`, none of the location manager delegate functions were called, although `startUpdatingLocation` was reached.

I have no view controller because it's inside a react native plugin.
The Location When In Use Usage Description is set in the info.plist and the deinit function was never called.
Furthermore, the location permission is also granted.

Does someone know what is missing?

Comment: What is the scope/life cycle of `LocationService`? Is it a local var? If yes, then it might be deallocated too soon, before the delegate methods get called.

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol LocationManagerDelegate {
func didAuthorized()
func didUpdateLocation(location: CLLocation?, isFirst: Bool)
}

final class LocationManager: NSObject {

static let shared = LocationManager()

let delegates = MulticastDelegate<LocationManagerDelegate>()

private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var currentLocation: CLLocation?

var isStop = false
var denied = false


override init() {
    super.init()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
  }
}

func request() {
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
        self.denied = true
        
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        self.isStop = false
        self.denied = false
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
    default:
        break
    }
 }
}

func stop() {
self.isStop = true
self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
 }
}
```

This is extension

```
extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
        self.isStop = false

        if self.denied {
            self.denied = false
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        self.delegates.invoke(invocation: { $0.didAuthorized() })
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.first, isStop == false else {
        return
    }

    var isFirst = false
    if self.currentLocation == nil {
        isFirst = true
    }

    self.currentLocation = location
    self.delegates.invoke(invocation: { $0.didUpdateLocation(location: location, isFirst: isFirst) })
}


func checkLocationPermission() -> Bool {
    
    // check the permission status
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        return true
    default:break
    }
    return false
 }
}
```

maybe you must use this:
static let shared = LocationManager()

when I want location , I use:
LocationManager.shared.request()

this works for me

Comment: Thank you very much for your skeleton, @Cavidan Məmmədli.

I found out what was wrong: I didn't post it, but I had two classes defined in the same file. Just for testing purposes. When I put the LocationService in a new file, it works. I didn't think this could have any effect, but it seems to.

Thanks for your fast and detailed help! 

Comment: The `static let shared = LocationManager()` might fix it it your previous `LocationService` was deallocated too soon.

Answer (score 0):

First you must ask permission from user

self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

Comment: The permission is granted. It was asked before :)

Comment: Did you see any error on debug area?

Comment: No, unfortunately not...

Comment: I share with you my skeleton class.